# Can I get a JSON value from the internet without flashing a custom FW on EV3?

Tags: ev3, programming

Got an EV3 for X-Mas. My old NXT brick was broken. So now I have a ton of motors and sensors and all. First project I'd like to create a Bitcoin piggy bank which performs some actions when it gets new funds. I would therefore need to query a JSON value every x seconds.

So is there a way to do this? Is there a way to give EV3 access the internet?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with a 3rd party operating system. On the EV3, these generally run from a microSD card and do not touch the firmware in the flash memory of the EV3, so technically, you are not flashing a custom firmware (think dual-boot). The major 3rd party OSes are [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org), [leJOS](http://lejos.org) and [MonoBrick](http://monobrick.dk). All of these have Internet access from the brick itself.

To do this using the official firmware only, you won't be able to access the Internet directly from the brick. So, you will have to have an application on a computer or a smartphone that accesses the Internet and relays information to the EV3 using Bluetooth messaging.

Comment: OK thank you. Good to know. Feeding a message from a PC would be an option also. I will look into these OSes. Used to run RobotC on my old NXT brick. Dual-Boot is of course even nicer so you don't have to wipe the FW when switching back and forth.